# How to get the resultcode from a sub-sub-child activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Let's say I have 3 activities.
Activity A starts the activity B, activity B starts the activity C.

In the activity A I have the code

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, SOME_NUMBER);
```

In the activity B I have the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
finish(); // this activity should die and start the C activity
startActivityForResult(i, SOME_NUMBER);
```

Finally in the activity C I have the code:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

My problem is that the activity A does not receive the resultCode that the activity C has put.
My onActivityResult(int, int Intent) method in the activity A look like this:

```
switch(requestCode){
case SOME_NUMBER:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        // the activity C has returned RESULT_OK
    }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        // the activity C has returned RESULT_CANCELED
    }
break;
}
```

It always enter in the else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED).
I want to know how to pass the correct resultCode from C activity to A activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**finish()**-  Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.
     So you are always getting Resultcode 0 (RESULT_CANCELED = 0).

**Example**:

**first_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="70px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FirstActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.startforresultdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
     TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);      
        textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sampleData", "This is Sample Data");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
       String msg = data.getStringExtra("returnedData");
       textView.setText(msg);
      }else{
          Log.i("babu", "requestCode "+requestCode+" resultCode "+resultCode);
          //String msg = data.getStringExtra("returnedData");
           textView.setText("requestCode "+requestCode+" resultCode "+resultCode);
      }
     }

}
```

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

     Intent intent;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      intent= getIntent();
      String msg = intent.getStringExtra("sampleData");
      msg += ", Added at Second";

      Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
      intent2 .putExtra("sampleData", msg);   
      startActivityForResult(intent2, 10);
      //finish();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==10){
       String msg = data.getStringExtra("returnedData");
       intent.putExtra("returnedData", msg);
       setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
       finish();
      }
     }



}
```

**ThirdActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.startforresultdemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ThirdActivity extends Activity{    
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Intent intent= getIntent();
      String msg = intent.getStringExtra("sampleData");
      msg += ", Added at Third";
      intent.putExtra("returnedData", msg);
      setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
      finish();
     }

}
```

OR Add following code into your class as your wish. you can get result from your `third activity`.

**FirstActivity.java:**

```
  if(getIntent().getStringExtra("returnedData") != null){          
              Intent intent= getIntent();
              String msg = intent.getStringExtra("returnedData");           
              textView.setText(msg);

       }else{
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("sampleData", "This is Sample Data");          
           startActivity(intent);
       }

       SecondActivity.java:
      intent= getIntent();
      String msg = intent.getStringExtra("sampleData");
      msg += ", Added at Second";     
      Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
      intent2 .putExtra("sampleData", msg);     
      finish(); 
      startActivity(intent2);

      ThirdActivity.java
      Intent intent= getIntent();
      String msg = intent.getStringExtra("sampleData");
      msg += ", Added at Third";
      Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
      intent1.putExtra("returnedData", msg);
      startActivity(intent1);
      finish();
```

Comment: Ok @babu-k great answer! But the reason why the activity 2 should be finished is beacause if the user is in the activity 3 and he presses the Back button, the app should return to the activity 1 not the activity 2.

Comment: Ok.@Yakamoko , I have edited my answer as your requirement.Please have a look .

Comment: your answer is perfect!! Thank you so much.